# GPUs out of memory even in reading small data? Using "Quadro m1000m 4GB GPU"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, theano

```
Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[256,128,3,3] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
```

Here I am trying to use vgg for learning concepts of deep learning using Fast.ai course. When I am trying to read a small data of 4 images also it shows the error given in the above space. Here is the link to the vgg16 file that I am using:
https://github.com/fastai/courses/blob/master/deeplearning1/nbs/vgg16.py

Here my path in the below code is the path to the sample data which contains 4-5 images only.

```
path = "data/dogscats/sample/"

import vgg16
from vgg16 import Vgg16

batch_size = 4
vgg = Vgg16()
# Grab a few images at a time for training and validation.
# NB: They must be in subdirectories named based on their category
#batches = vgg.get_batches(path+'train', batch_size=batch_size)
val_batches = vgg.get_batches(path+'valid', batch_size=batch_size*2)
vgg.finetune(batches)
vgg.fit(batches, val_batches, nb_epoch=1)
```

Comment: You should add that you are using a "Quadro m1000m 4GB GPU"

Comment: sorry @MartinThoma so now how to approach to solve this issue.

Comment: Try to execute it on CPU. What happens? Which error message do you get? (And please add this to the question!)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. Actually Tensowflow version was requiring a lot of memory so I changed the Keras backend to Theano and that solved the issue there is nothing to do with VGG here I guess.
Switching can be done in the .keras folder in keras.json file and change the backend to theano.